A question about shirk because of the games
Assalamu Alaikum.
I was playing a game and in this game there was a ceremony in honor of their fictional goddess. And being a Muslim in real life, I did what was in this game in order to further complete the game according to the plot. The first time I didn't understand what I was doing, and when I started doing it the second time, I thought, "isn't this shirk?" And when I finished doing it the second time, I already realized what I had done. I don't believe in everything that happened in this game.
Have I committed shirk?
